# MercadoPago devuelve valores en Null

Tags: php, mercadopago

He clonado exactamente todo lo que dice el chekout API de MercadoPago (cambiando los valores de acces token por los míos):

https://www.mercadopago.com.mx/developers/es/guides/online-payments/checkout-api/receiving-payment-by-card

El problema radica en que a pesar de haber clonado todo el proyecto que **MP** deja de pruebas siguen saliendo errores, el más común:

```
>Cannot read property 'payer_costs' of undefined
```

Adicional a eso si hacemos el POST con el error de arriba, devuelve todos los datos en `NULL`.

¿Hay algo que se deba hacer adicional a lo que Mercado Pago dice? Tengo el SDK 1.9.0 (última versión) - PHP

Agradecería si tienen una guía completa o algo similar de la integración de pagos con tarjeta de Mercado Pago.

Comment: En cuál lenguaje estás trabajando? Usas frameworks?

Comment: @NoobDev Solamente PHP amigo y no, no uso ningún framework